# jQuery .ajax() call to host equal to current page failing

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm building an interface to a backend system using JavaScript (with Jquery).

The system "hosts" both the interface itself as a webpage, and the api with which it communicates through an $.ajax call.

When I open up the interface at `http://localhost:4242`, set the api host (url value for the $.ajax call) to `http://localhost:4242/api` and attempt the $.ajax call, it will timeout.

It seems to be because both addresses are equal, because if I change either of them to the local ip address or hostname, or open the interface from the html file, the request works as expected.

Is this a limitation of the $.ajax function, or something else?

Edit: more info!

- the backend never receives the request
- the ajax request does appear in the network console (pending, and canceled after it times out)
- the `$.ajax({error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){ //stuff }})` is triggered after the timeout value is reached with textStatus and errorThrown both == 'timeout'

Okay.. if I change the type from POST to GET, suddenly it works like a charm. Wut?

I thought it might have to so with the 'jsonp' datatype, as it is intended for crossdomain communication but changing to 'json' if the domain is equal does not have an effect.

Comment: As long as protocols, domains and ports match, it shouldn't be a problem at all. Try using just the URL /api and see if that works.

Comment: What do you mean by timeout? You get a TimeOut error or the request does not return anything? I fyou don't get any result it may be bacuse the URL response is cached on the browser

Comment: I've added some more info: most notably that the request is succesful if the type is 'GET' instead of 'POST'.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such limitation of $.ajax, otherwise life would just be impractical in this world :)

If you are sure the request is being sent (check your Network tab in Chrome or Firebug!) and is really timeout, then sure, it's most likely an issue with your back-end but that sounds weird. What do you mean by 'when I open the interface from the html file'?

Comment: The backend devs tell me the data is never received; it is being sent according to the network tab. The interface is a webpage that can either be opened via file:///path/server.html or through http://localhost:4242 or another host.

Comment: I assume that server.html isn't a real html page and that the .html is to request a html response? Anyway, the issue may be that the server doesn't respond to the Ajax call (which should have the XMLHttpRequest  header) properly... it's hard to tell without more information. All I can say for sure is that $.ajax isn't directly at fault!

Comment: The .html is an actual html page, it provides the interface that communicates with /api, which returns a json object.

Answer (score 0):

We've now resolved the issue. It turns out that if using `dataType: 'jsonp'`  without it being a crossdomain request, the crossDomain option needs to be set to true. It's almost logical.

Why it was working fine with `type: 'GET'` remains a mystery.